# FeatherJS and SwaggerUI: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger-ui, feathersjs

I tried to implement Swagger UI module in my project based on FeathersJS framework as shown below:

```
...
messageService.docs = {
      description: 'A service to send and receive messages',
      definitions: {
        messages: {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "text"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "text": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "The message text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    const app = feathers()
      ....
      .configure(swagger({
        docsPath: '/docs',
        info: {
          title: 'A test',
          description: 'A description'
        }
      }))
      .use('/messages', messageService);
```

But I got this error message. How can I fix it?

```
Resolver error at paths./messages.get.responses.200.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/messages list does not exist in document
```

Comment: Can you post the generated Swagger JSON/YAML file?

Comment: i have no JSON/YAML file, it's not specified on https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-swagger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message obviously you have to add the **'messages list'** in messageService.docs definitions properties.

As follows:

```
messageService.docs = {
  description: 'A service to send and receive messages',
  definitions: {
    messages: {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "text"
      ],
    },
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "The message text"
      }
    },

    // add message list definitions
    'messages list': {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "text"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The message text"
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

You can read the complete example in the [docs](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-swagger#example-with-feathers-generate-app).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sequelize you might want to try https://github.com/alt3/sequelize-to-json-schemas. It will automatically generate the model schemas for you.